# Mysqldump: Can you change the name of the table you're inserting into?

Tags: mysql

I am using `mysqldump` to transfer a table from one database to another.

```
mysqldump -h host -u user -p password -e --single-transaction --no-create- info --default-character-set=utf8 --complete-insert --result-file=thisisaresult db table
```

I was wondering, however, if there is a way to change the name of the table you insert into? For example, I'd like this to insert into `table_staging`, or something like that. Is this possible, or am I going to have to just use `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is possible when dumping data because there may be FK references to the table you are changing.

If there are no FK references to the table you wish to change then it is possible to just hand edit the resulting dump file:

```
CREATE TABLE `old_table_name`
```

Becomes

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name`
```

My recommendation would be to dump the data, re-import it into your new database, then run the alters to rename your table.

Comment: You also have to edit the `INSERT INTO` statement.

Answer (score 27):

After creating a `mysql` dump file you could do the following:

```
sed -i 's/`old-table-name`/`new-table-name`/g' old-table-name.dump
```

The `sed` command will search and replace the old table name with the new table name from within the mysql dump file.

Comment: I used this but I also added the ` around the table name, to make sure it was not data in the table somewhere. so it would then look like this: `sed -i 's/\`old-table-name\`/\`new-table-name\`/g' old-table-name.dump`

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome

Comment: I think this could be really slow with a dump of 4GB :(

Comment: For Mac Os X users, this command will fail when using the OS-provided sed (`/usr/bin/sed`).You can `brew install gnu-sed` and use `gsed` and it will work as described though.

Answer (score 13):

You can change table name on the fly when you create the dump using Unix sed.

```
# create dump of mytable, renaming it to mytable_new

$ mysqldump -umyuser -pmypass -hmyhost mydb mytable |\
  sed -e 's/`mytable`/`mytable_new`/'| gzip -c > mydb_mytable_new.dump.gz


# restoring in another database:

$ gunzip -c mydb_mytable_new.dump.gz | mysql -umyuser2 -pmypass2 -hmyhost2 mydb2
```