# MySQL - Merge data from two tables (they are on different servers)

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

Suppose you have table A (database named test) on server 1 and you have table A (database named test) on server 2.

Table A has rows like this

(1, 'first row table A')

(2, 'second row table A')

Note: First column do not use auto increment

Table B has rows like this

(1, 'first row table B')

(2, 'second row table B')

I would like to get on a third server a table named A  (and database named test) with the following rows

(1, 'first row table A')

(2, 'second row table A')

(3, 'first row table B')

(4, 'second row table B')

I tried using mysqldump but first column is causing issue 'duplicate key' when trying to import the second dump. I am using MySQL. This should be done for multiple tables. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why aren't you using auto-increment for the first column?

Comment: @Barmar The first column does not use auto-increment. I don't know why, I didn't create that column

Answer (score 1):

Load the dump into a table with a different name. See [Mysqldump: Can you change the name of the table you're inserting into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042723/mysqldump-can-you-change-the-name-of-the-table-youre-inserting-into) for how you can rename the table in the dump file.

Then merge the data from the temp table, adjusting the first column so they're outside the range from the original table.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (col1, col2)
SELECT col1 + increment, col2 FROM temp_TableA
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(col1) AS increment FROM TableA) AS t
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you scale your answer? I should do it for multiple tables

Comment: You could write a stored procedure that creates the `INSERT` query dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. How would you avoid inserting repeated rows? When I say repeated, I mean rows where the only difference is the id column (the rest of the columns are equal)

Comment: You could delete from `temp_TableA` any rows that are equal to a row in `TableA`

Comment: Thanks. How would you make all this work taking into account that both tables are on different servers? It's not clear to me

Comment: You're dumping one of the tables, then loading it into the temporary table on the other server so you can do the merge.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add to your answer an example about that stored procedure you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, that's more of a project than I have time to do, so I'll just point you in the right direction. You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the list of columns in the tables, and `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine them into a comma-separated list. Concatenate this into a string with the rest of the `INSERT` query and use `PREPARE STATEMENT` and `EXECUTE`.