# How can you update one database with data from another before overwriting one with the other in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the data before merging/overwriting one of the databases. I have two databases; one local and one remote db with table `table` in each. I make an sql dump from the remote server so I get `remotebackup.sql`.

**Description**
I have one simple table `table` with id, count and data. Ids are unique. The local db table has more ids but the count is old data where the remote db table has the count data of interest.

```
Remote:
|id|count|data|
| 1| 132 |x   |
| 2| 32  |y   |

Local:
|id|count|data|
| 1| 130 |x   |
| 2| 21  |y   |
| 3| 4   |z   |
```

**Problem:**
I want to update the count in the count in the local database table with the numbers from remote database before dumping sql from the local to the remote server (so that I get the data with id 3 also).

**What is the easiest way to do it?** I am thinking of generating an sql file and doing something like

```
source remotebackup.sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the data from the dump file into a new table in the local db. See [Mysqldump: Can you change the name of the table you're inserting into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042723/mysqldump-can-you-change-the-name-of-the-table-youre-inserting-into) for how you can rename the table in the dump file before loading.

Then merge this into the table using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, count, data)
SELECT id, count, data FROM remote_tablename
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = VALUES(count)
```